# How to create a datagrid in GTK without GTK Sharp?

Tags: gtk, programming, libraries, mono

I would like to write a GTK program with a datagrid. However GTK Sharp is for the .NET Framework. Is there any non-.NET library or framework with a datagrid that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

GTKSharp is a c# wrapper for the native c GTK+

You can use GTKSharp on ubuntu using mono. (it is used much more on mono then on .net)

However if you don't want to use .net/mono then you can use GTK+ from c, c++, python and many other languages.

A GTK+ TreeView can be used as a grid:

A https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkTreeView.html

Comment: i search GTK+ from c with datagrid, no such thing exist

Comment: @M-Askman GTK+ TreeView can be used as a grid, see my update.

Comment: Treeview is a hack, it was meant for showing treeview as name suggests. It doesn't even support odd/even color styling. I think GTK doesn't have anything similar 'datagrid' which someone can directly use.